# How can I map the names of an array of objects to change the field names?

Tags: javascript

I am sending data from my client to a method on my WebApi controller that accepts a class of ResponseFromClient. As it's WebApi this handles all the conversion from JSON and changes any field names to match the case convention differences between javascript and C#:

```
public class ResponseFromClient
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AnswerDetail> Answers { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
}
public class AnswerDetail
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool? Correct { get; set; }
    public bool? Response { get; set; }
}
```

In Javascript I have an array called `ans` with each element looking like this:

```
qs.ans[index].id = element.answerId;
qs.ans[index].c = null;
qs.ans[index].r = false;
qs.ans[index].text = element.text;
```

I need to send the contents of a Javascript object `responseFromClient` to the C# server program:

```
        var responseFromClient = {
            questionId: qs.q,
            answers: qs.ans,
            task: task
        };
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: responseFromClient
        })
```

Is there a simple way that I can set the `answers` field in the javascript variable `responseFromClient` so that it receives an array that contains objects that map to the `AnswerDetail` class. In other words I need to change it so that the answers gets and array of objects that are like this:

```
old > new

id > AnswerID
c  > Correct
t  > Text
r  > Response
```

I was thinking to do it like I do where I remap qs.q > questionId. However ans is an array so I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it not easier allround to map the object onto the class in your JavaScript

```
qs.ans[index].answerId = element.answerId;
qs.ans[index].correct = null;
qs.ans[index].response = false;
qs.ans[index].text
```

or

in the ajax call

```
data: { "answerId" : responseFromClient.id, 
        "correct": responseFromClient.c, 
        "response": responseFromClient.t, 
        "text": responseFromClient.text }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remap the values you want with arrays of old => new keys. There are more advanced ways of doing this, but I don't know all the details of your case...

```
function remap(obj, old_keys, new_keys){
    var len = old_keys.length;
    var new_obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        new_obj[new_keys[i]] = obj[old_keys[i]];
    }
    return new_obj;
}

var len = ans.length;
var old_keys = ["id", "c", "r", "text"];
var new_keys = ["AnswerId", "Correct", "Response", "Text"]

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ans[i] = remap(ans[i], old_keys, new_keys);
}
```